# What is "map" matching exactly in Rack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

Say I have this in Rack:

```
map '/great' do
  run Test.new
end
```

This URL works great: `site.com/great/stuff` but this does NOT: `site.com/greatstuff`. I've read that `map` should match anything that STARTS WITH the the arg name, but this doesn't seem to be the case, with cases like these.

Is there any detailed specification on how this works?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'd say it matches `'/great/'` and any `'/great/'` subfolder. It doesn't match paths merely starting with `great`, though.

Comment: Ya, you're right the documentation is really poor.  It looks like the regex used to match is in here: https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/urlmap.rb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The confusion seems to be conceptual.

It does match ***paths*** starting with `/great`. That is `/great`, `/great/`, `/great/stuff` and so on.
What it doesn't do is match ***strings*** starting with `/great`. Like `/greatstuff`.

`/greatstuff` and `/great`are completely different paths. Think of paths as a tree structure.

---

There is no way to do *"string path matching"* with barebones `map` AFAIK, but you could add your own rack middleware that looks at the request path and dispatches appropriately.

---

If you want to double check the implementation, here are the two relevant places: [1](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/urlmap.rb#L35), [2](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/urlmap.rb#L60-L63).

```
Regexp.new("^#{Regexp.quote(location).gsub('/', '/+')}(.*)", nil, 'n')
```

This basically creates a regex out of a path that requires a string to start with that path (multiple `/` ignored) in order to match. Aka:

```
to_regex('/foo/bar') # => /^\/+foo\/+bar(.*)/n
```

*In case you are wondering, the `n` flag sets the encoding to ASCII.*

If the string matches, a few more checks are performed. Namely that the remainder of the matched path is either non-existent or starts with `/`. The latter ensures that you won't match things like `/greatstuff` with `/great`, as `stuff` doesn't start with `/`.

```
next unless !rest || rest.empty? || rest[0] == ?/
```

Comment: Did you find any related documentation? That was my conclusion too, but I didn't bother to look at the sourcecode.

Comment: @EricDuminil, added implementation reference.